# Appending traverse-tree string to json-object to retrieve json-data in python

Tags: json, python-2.7

Here is my sample json data:

```
 {
  "id": "67362003",
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "3": 2,
      "43": 30,
      "c": "jack",
      "d": "trail",
      "e": [
        {
          "f": {
            "g": "Father",
            "h": "Mother"
          }
        }
      ],
      "p": [
        {
          "q": {
            "r": "Aunt",
            "s": "Uncle"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Wrote a method, *objpath* which will get the each input from user-config: like **[root:id, root:a:b:e[0]]** and returns each path as **['id]** at first call.. and for second call.. it returns **['a']['b']['e'][0]** which I can able to read and print in my code of wrapper.

I am able to print *print (obj['a']['b']['e'][0])* this manner.. In that, objpath method will return '['a']['b']['e'][0]' part as string. So, here how can I convert it to *obj['a']['b']['e'][0]* format.. It may be simple, I tried multiple ways.. But somehow it's breaking with type of string/list/dict... Below is my python-wrapper to do same

```
file_json = 'config_lib/sample.json'
lf = open(file_json, 'r')
obj = json.loads(lf.read())
skeys = ["root:id", "root:a:b:e[0]"]
for skey in skeys:
    returns = JsonParser(obj, skey)
    # Its returning string.
    print type(returns)     # <type 'str'>
    print (returns)         # *['id']* at first itereation, *['a']['b']['e'][0]* at second iteration
    print (obj[returns])  # how to print the obj value here ??? I am not getting
```

I need to print *obj['a']['b']['e'][0]* and *obj['id']*

Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

By converting the string to json-object resolved the issue..

```
print ("Returned value is:", eval('obj' + returns))
```